# Added service reference appears in a completely different namespace

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, service-reference

So as headline says .. I wrote a service for project A - then I needed a similar service for project B so instead of inventing and building the wheel a second time, I copied the service, edited every name and reference to point to project B.. but to my surprise when adding the service reference it still is seen in the namespace of project A instead of Project B ...

How can I change that behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a wrong understanding of adding a service reference, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2019) to add a service reference to the application. It is very convenient to add service references for different applications. Only the url of the service is needed to establish a service reference. Or use [channelfactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory) to call the service.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else stumbled upon the same ..

the solution is pretty simple - just go to the service's properties in VS - check the AssemblyName and Standard Namespace on the "Application" page of said properties - I just found that those 2 fields referenced the old service name and namespace .. after changing them, all came together as wanted.

And @Theobald - certainly I've created quite a few services but this is the single one that was "too identical" to bother to invent it a second time ...